# Why is my observable still undefined when I subscribe to it?

Tags: angular, service, observable, subscription, interaction

I'm making a simple Angular-webshop and I'm sending data between two components through a service using Subject and Observable.

For some reason, in my CartComponent, "items" is undefined, why?

I can't wrap my head around it, am I missing something vital?

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICartItem } from '../interfaces/ICartItem';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { IMovie } from '../interfaces/IMovie';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
  export class CartService {
  private cartSource = new Subject<ICartItem[]>();
  private cart: ICartItem[] = [];

  currentShoppingCart = this.cartSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  addMovie(movie: IMovie) {
    let foundMovie = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
      if (movie.id === this.cart[i].movie.id) {
        this.cart[i].amount++;
        foundMovie = true;
      }
    }
    if (!foundMovie) {
    this.cart.push({movie, amount: 1});
    }
    this.cartSource.next(this.cart);
  }

  removeMovie(movie: IMovie) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
      if (movie.id === this.cart[i].movie.id) {
        this.cart[i].amount--;
    } if (this.cart[i].amount < 1) {
      this.cart.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
    this.cartSource.next(this.cart);
  }

}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from '../services/cart.service';
import { ICartItem } from '../interfaces/ICartItem';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  items: ICartItem[];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  decreaseAmount(movie) {
    this.cartservice.removeMovie(movie);
  }
  increaseAmount(movie) {
    this.cartservice.addMovie(movie);
  }

  constructor(private cartservice: CartService) {
    this.cartservice.currentShoppingCart.subscribe( cart => {
      this.items = cart;
      console.log(this.items);
   });
      //This one will be undefined
      console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

I expect items to contain the movie-array but now console.log(this.items); will give me "undefined".

Comment: Are you sure you are calling, `increaseAmount()` method with some valid movie data ? Also post your code of `ngModule` code where you declaring the service and component.

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MoviesComponent,
    CartComponent,
    DisplayMovieComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [CartService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Comment: Yes I'm sure, i can console log this.cart in the service and get the correct array.

Comment: I have read through it a couple of times now, I am not finding any issues. Maybe there is something wrong with your imports, can you share them as well?

Comment: I added them in the main question!

Comment: Ok so it is actually working to console.log(this.items); BUT for some reason I can't access the data outside of that code block, it's like items: ICartItem[]; and this.items = cart; is not connecting

Comment: Are you trying to display the value of items in your html-template? As you are using a Subject, initially the value of items will be undefined. A couple of ways of solving this. 1. Escape undefined properties in the template with a "?", for example like "item?.movie.id". 2. Give items an initial value in your component.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do. I know of those solutions, but right now I never get access to my real array anyway, that's the problem. I added a new line to demonstrate the issue, take a look at //This one will be undefined. Is that more clear? =/

Comment: Yes it is more clear :) and it makes sense that "this.items" will be undefined at that point. The code inside your subscribe block is asynchronous and will be called at a later point, so when the "console.log(this.items);" in the end of your constructor is invoked, no value has been given to this.items.

Comment: Ok! What could I do to make it work? Do you have any solution apart for the two you gave me?